# Getting an Electron app approved by Facebook

Tags: facebook, electron, facebook-javascript-sdk

So i am building an Electron desktop app that uses Facebook to authenticate the user and then grab his friends to make it easier for the user to create groups within the app.
My issue is that in order for an app to have access to a user's friends (user_friends permission) it needs to be approve by Facebook, but Facebook does not have a 'desktop app' platform you can pick when submitting your app for review
The way i handle the login:

- Wrap a web page (that has a Facebook login button, using the js sdk) that's on my site inside an electron window
- When that window gets redirected after login, grab the access token and use the [node facebook api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb) to grab the user info and the friends

tl;dr; how do i get my Electron app approved by Facebook for the user_friends permission?

Comment: Desktop apps can be submitted using the Website platform – put in a dummy URL, and explain very clearly in your review instructions that this is not in fact a website app, and where/how they can test it, if possible; otherwise, be very descriptive in your screencast(s).